# What do I need to do for this for loop to make a full dataframe and not just the first row?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, for-loop, append

I made this for loop:

```
for(gamma in seq(from = -0.07, to = -1, by = -0.01))  {
  demand <<- data.frame(gamma = gamma,
                        avgcommute = converge(gamma))
}
```

What do I need to change in it to make it not just make one row of -1, converge(gamma)?

For simplicity, let's just assume that converge() does this:

```
converge <- function(gamma) {
gamma * 2
}
```

Comment: HI. I tryed your code but get an error, because converge() is not knownfrom which library is converge()?

Comment: to solve your problem you could use rbind() inside the loop.

Comment: @pbraeutigm I added some more code to clear that up. I'm not sure how exactly to use rbind() here.

Answer (score 0):

```
# common example source 
(myseq <- seq(from = -0.07, to = -1, by = -0.01))
  
#manually
slen <- length(myseq)
mydf <- vector(mode = "list",length=slen)
for(i in seq_len(slen))  {
  mydf[[i]] <- data.frame(x = myseq[i])
}

(mydf <- do.call(rbind,mydf))

# idiomaticly

(mydf2 <- do.call(rbind,lapply(myseq, \(x_)data.frame(x=x_))))

identical(mydf,mydf2)
```